# Gratuitous parentheses around expression

Tags: javascript, eslint

I have this statement

```
if ((value && value !== "something") || (value2 && value2 !== "somethingelse")) {
}
```

And ESLint is telling me this:

> Gratuitous parentheses around expression.

Can I remove the inner brackets? I thought that this would break the if statement.

Comment: What made you think that? Of the operators you're using, per [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), `!==` has the highest precedence, then `&&`, then `||`, so ESLint isn't lying to you.

Comment: But, with this kind of statements, I'd leave them. *Much* more obvious for a human reader

Comment: I always put parentheses around boolean operations like this. Remember that linting is not as important as readability for you and your colleagues.

Comment: I think so too, I was never assuming ESLint was lying to me, I assumed the brackets were necessary as I have learnd so in school, that's why I'm asking. But I'll leave them to improve readability

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Operator Precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) you can remove inner parentheses:

```js
var value = '1';
var value2 = 'somethingelse';
if ((value && value !== "something") || (value2 && value2 !== "somethingelse")) {
    console.log('ORIG: ok');
} else {
    console.log('ORIG: nok');
}


var value = '1';
var value2 = 'somethingelse';
if (value && value !== "something" || value2 && value2 !== "somethingelse") {
    console.log('ok');
} else {
    console.log('nok');
}
```